# How can I eliminate cheating for an online survey?

Tags: php

How can I eliminate "as much as possible" cheating on a survey? So I want a survey to be completed by one computer at a time.

I currently capture the IP address but an IP address is a dynamic so that is a problem. Please IP address can be spoofed I think.

So how can I improve my security but allowing only one PC at a time to complete the survey?

"Cheat" means submitting the survey multiple time.
I created the survey using PHP.

Thanks

Comment: If it is a survey, how can people 'cheat'?

Comment: "One PC at a time"? Do you mean *"every PC only once"*?

Comment: What rules are you trying to enforce, how do you define 'cheating'?

Comment: Once PC at a time. so if a user use computer to submit a survey then no one else can use the same PC to submit another survey. Justin, there are many ways people can submit the survey over and over.

Comment: So, *"every PC only once"*. "One at a time" means that two PC can't submit a survey together at the same time but have to wait in line until the other is finished.

Comment: many can take the survey at the same time but once one submitting can be made from one machine.

Answer (score 3):

1. Require participants to register with their email address
2. Track IP addresses
3. Set and track a browser cookie
4. Send SMS to user's cell phone that they have to enter
5. Require participants to purchase and setup a retina scanner on their computer =)

Kidding aside, I think the SMS is probably going to be the most reliable and yet enforceable option on that list. You can require participants to enter their cell number, use a service like Twilio to easily send them an SMS code, and now it becomes difficult for the same person to submit the survey again. I realize this is tracking users not computers, but I think it gets awfully close to what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: @Mike Did this help you at all? Does the SMS option sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how far you want to go.

An easy to implement solution would be to set an [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) on any browser that completes the survey. This will be really easy to defeat (clear your recent history or use private navigation) but may be enough for non tech-savvy users.

A much harder solution (with potential false positives) would be to use [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) in addition to their IP address, netblock and evercookie and store all these info separately in a database.

When someone new tries to complete the survey, compare their info against what you have in the database and increment a score for each item that matches. If the score is above a predefined constant, you may have caught someone trying to retake the survey.

The hard part would be to adjust that constant and maybe give an unique multiplier for each item depending on the uniqueness of the item (an user-agent isn't that unique, an IP is better, and the list of installed plugins is even better, for example).

Finally you should ban Tor Exit Nodes using [this list](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py) (enter the IP of your server and their script will return a list of all exit nodes that can reach your server) and open proxies/VPN services using one of those [blacklists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_blacklists).

Comment: Blocking Tor nodes seems over the top. First of all, there are many other kinds of proxies you should worry about if you're worried about proxies, and secondly cookies work the same whether it's via a proxy or not.

Comment: @deceze It doesn't have anything to do with cookies, it's just a separate feature that will hopefully limit the "cheating" but yes you are right, blocking all other proxies (based on various [blacklists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_blacklists) is also necessary.